# skip lines that contain semi-colon in text file

Tags: c#

How can I skip lines in a text file that contain a semi-colon at the beginning of a line? I'm currently reading a text file in with server names which works fine. I want to throw a semi-colon at the beginning of a line to comment it out in case a server is going into maintenance mode.

Comment: In what context?  You can just read in the line and do nothing if the first character is a ';', but only if the context allows that.

Comment: So annoying, before i could answer there were already 6 answers posted..

Comment: Do you also want to skip lines that have 1st non-whitespace character semicolon, or just 1st character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines( path );
foreach( var line in lines )
{
    if( line.StartsWith( ";" ) )
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. BioBuckyBall, I didn't think to use the "continue" option. I was playing around with the "startswith" function but I guess I had a brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: OK, so we can make this easier...

```
foreach (var currentLine in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\somefile.txt"))
{
    if (currentLine.StartsWith(";")) continue;

    // Pretend this is the function you want to do below.
    ProcessLine(currentLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!textline.StartsWith(";"))
  // do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using something that derives from [System.IO.TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) you could `Peek` at the next character and see if it's a semicolon.  Otherwise read the line and check the first character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        var allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("SOME-PATH");
        var filteredLines = from l in allLines
            where !l.StartsWith(";")
        select l;
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are asking this question for C#.

In this case you can use a [startswith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx#Y114) from string class, i am not sure how is your code but i think this can help you:

```
using System;
using System.IO; 

class Program {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {
        string filePath = @"test.txt";
        string line; 
        string fileContent = "";

        if (File.Exists( filePath )) {
            StreamReader file = null;
            try {
                file = new StreamReader( filePath );
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
                        if (!line.StartsWith(";")){
                                Console.WriteLine( line );
                                fileContent += line;        
                        }
                }
            } finally {
                if (file != null)
                    file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(string line in readLines()) 
{
   if (line[0] == ';') continue;
   ...   
}
```

Comment: Thanks again everyone. You helped me out greatly and gave me several viable options.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `StartWith` will help

```
string line = null;
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt"))
{
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!line.StartsWith(";"))
        {
            // do thomething
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in .NET 4.0:

```
  File.ReadLines("c:\test.txt").Where(x => !x.StartsWith(";"));
```

Maybe you want AsParallel

```
  File.ReadLines("c:\test.txt").AsParallel().Where(x => !x.StartsWith(";"));
```

;)